# toString, Nullpointerexception

Tags: java, object, reference, nullpointerexception, tostring

I'm getting a Nullpointerexception when trying to get the trees name from the arraylist. I've tested just getting the name alone but i'm still getting this error. All i want to do is know which Equipment is cutting which tree.

```
public class TreeTester {
public static void main(String[] args) {   
    Tree trees = new Tree("Trees");
    Tree tree1 = new Tree("Ash Tree");
    trees.addTree(tree1);
```

Tree Class

```
public Class Tree{
    private ArrayList<Tree> theTrees;
    private String treeName;

    //Forgot these
    Tree(String trees //There are more but not relevent) {
        theTrees = new ArrayList<Tree>();
    }

    Tree(String treeName){
        this.treeName = treeName;
    }
    //

    public boolean addTree(Tree newTree){
        theTrees.add(newTree);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String s = getTreeName();
        return s;
    }

    private String getTreeName() {
        return this.treeName; }
    }
```

//------------------Shortened for ease--------------------------//
Just imagine the missing vars and contructor

```
public Class Equipment{
    private Tree TreeDetails;
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String s = "Using " + getEqupiment(); + "to cut " + setCutTree()
    }

    public boolean setCutTree(){
        this.treename = treename.toString(); //Nullpointer issue here
        return this.treecut = true;
        //getEquipment works fine
    }

}
```

Comment: but your member variable treename is still not initialized in the tree class. Where do you assign any value to treename?

Comment: your constructor should be as answered by Cyan.

Comment: Apart from the answer... Your constructor description is not correct here... Signature for both of them is Tree(String trees)... Please correct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to intialize the `theTrees` `ArrayList`

```
public class Tree {
   private ArrayList<Tree> theTrees = new ArrayList<Tree>();
```

You have also left out the one argument constructor of `Tree` that you are using in the `main` method. Since you are getting a `NullPointerException` even when accessing the name I assume this constructor does not initialize the `treeName` either.

With the constructor the class should look something like this:

```
public class Tree {

   private ArrayList<Tree> theTrees;
   private String treeName;

   public Tree(String treeName) {
      this.treeName = treeName;
      this.theTrees = new ArrayList<Tree>();
   } 
   ...
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add those for the original question, You'll see them there now.

Comment: You cannot have two constructors that both take a String as their only argument. That will not compile. Put all the initialization into one constructor.

Comment: The treeName constructor actually takes more input but I've shortened it for simplicity sake.

Comment: In that case make sure you add `this.treeName = trees;` to your `trees` construtor.